# How to deactivate a url in a specific profile in quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

I am developing an API with quarkus 1.11. I would like to make a call to another API but only locally I don't want it to be called in production.

I know what I can do:

```
ProfileManager.getActiveProfile() != "test"
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to configure it with some java annotation or in the aplication.properties as:

```
%dev.test.api/mp-rest/url=DISABLED
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Would this fit your use case? -> https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#using-a-runtime-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the configuration properties and the MP-restclient you cant deactivate and endpoint, only change the url to a different one.

But what you can do instead is create a configuration property similar to the one you suggested, then inject the property in your code and use it to call or not your endpoint, It is similar to the logic you do the profile manager, but you will have more control over the invocation.

For example this could be the properties.

```
%dev.test.api.enabled=true
%prod.test.api.enabled=false
```

Then inject the properties like in this example [using the injection capabilities](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#inject) of quarkus and cdi.

Then implementing the condition to check if the call must be made or not.

---

I think that you will not find any property to do not make a call, because at the end you are executing a method and waiting for an answer, and this behaviour cannot be altered by an endpoint property, only by code offering an alternative response or execution path.